# How to call stored procedure postgresql in SAP Powerbuilder (12.5)?

Tags: postgresql, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-2017

Anyone can help me?
I tried to call stored procedure from postgresql database in powerbuilder, but i got some problem like this.

[image: Stored Procedure in PostgreSQL]

[image: Function to Call SP in Powerbuilder]

[image: Error Result]

I really appreciate your help, thank you so much.

Comment: How are you connecting to postgres? ODBC?

Comment: yes, i used ODBC to connecting PB into postgresql